# Why A[2][3] is valid lvalue for the declaration int *A [10];

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
int *A [10];
```

why `A[2][3]` is a valid lvalue. As I understand in `A[2]` we store a pointer to an integer(Single integer not an array). So how can `[3]` in `A[2][3]` access it?

Comment: Why is code attempting this?

Comment: Its a homework question ?

Comment: C doesn't have bounds-checking. A pointer to a single `int` value could be seen as an array of a single element, and going out of bounds of any array leads to *undefined behavior*. It's the responsibility of your program to not go out of bounds.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude then what is the benefit of having a type of int *?

Comment: Because sometimes you want to point to a single `int` value? And considering that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element, passing an array of `int` (e.g. `int B[10];`) to a function would be the same as passing a pointer to an `int`, i.e. `int *`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Does that mean `int *A [10];` and `int[] *A [10];` are both same?

Comment: No. The first (`int *A[10];`) declares `A` as an array of ten pointer to `int`. The second (`int[] *A [10];`) in invalid syntax. If a pointer points to a single value or to the first element of an array is part of your program logic, the compiler itself doesn't really care (it doesn't even know). You should probably take some time to read a few books to learn more about pointers and arrays, or ask a teacher/tutor to help you (stackoverflow.com is not a tutoring site).

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this code can demonstrate how int pointer arrays can be used.

The goal is to create a buffer big enough to hold 30 integers. Then assign an int pointer to every 3rd address division of the allocated buffer.

So if a[0] is set to address 0x562437eea260.
Then that means a[1] will be set to address 0x562437eea26c approximately (sizeof(int) * 3), 12, bytes away.

Then the values at the pointer's address can be set by calling a[i][j]; assuming i is the index that chooses the address from the int pointer array and j is either 1, 2, or 3 depending on what number you wish to access.

Expected Output:

```
a[0] = 0x562437eea260
a[0][0] = 2
a[0][1] = 3
a[0][2] = 5

a[1] = 0x562437eea26c
a[1][0] = 3
a[1][1] = 3
a[1][2] = 7

a[2] = 0x562437eea278
a[2][0] = 9
a[2][1] = 2
a[2][2] = 3
```

In my example, I set all integers to random values

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define UNUSED(x)((void)(x))

#define TOTAL_INT_POINTERS 10
#define INTS_PER_POINTER 3

int main(const int argc, const char** const argv, const char** const envp) {
    UNUSED(argc); UNUSED(argv); UNUSED(envp);

    // Seed random number generator
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));

    // Create and array that will hold 10 int pointers
    int *a[TOTAL_INT_POINTERS] = {0};

    // Allocate memory for integers
    int *ptr = (int *)malloc((sizeof(int) * TOTAL_INT_POINTERS) * INTS_PER_POINTER);
    if(ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory for integers!\n");
        return (int)EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Assign pointers and values to each allocated space
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < TOTAL_INT_POINTERS; i++) {
        // Assign pointer array member
        a[i] = ptr + (i * INTS_PER_POINTER);

        // Print assigned address
        printf("a[%d] = %p\n", i, a[i]);

        // Give 3 integers their values and print out the result
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < INTS_PER_POINTER; j++) {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            printf("a[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, a[i][j]);
        }

        putchar('\n');
    }

    // Free up used memory
    free(ptr);

    return (int)EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in the comments, the compiler manages only the pointer and is not aware of the actual structure of your data. You can access array elements by index using square brackets or by using pointer arithmetics:

`A[i][j]` is equivalent to  `*(A[i] + j)` and also equivalent to `*(*(A+i) + j)`.

Note that you must ensure that the memory you are accessing is actually within the array bounds.

Further reading:

- [Multidimensional Pointer Arithmetic in C/C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multidimensional-pointer-arithmetic-in-cc/)
- [How to access two dimensional array using pointers in C programming?](https://codeforwin.org/2017/12/access-two-dimensional-array-using-pointers-c-programming.html)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `x` points to an `int` does not mean there are not more `int` next to that `int`, either before or after it or both.

If I have an array `int a[10]`, then `&a[5]` points to element 5 of the array, and `&[5] - 1` and `&a[5] + 1` point to elements 4 and 6. If I pass `&a[5]` to a subroutine as its parameter `int *x`, and that subroutine knows other elements exist, it may use `x[1]` to refer to element 6 of the array and `x[-1]` to refer to element 4.

Given `int *A[10]`, I can allocate as much memory as I want and assign its address to `A[0]`. Then `A[0][0]` points to space for the first `int` in that memory, `A[0][1]` points to space for the next `int`, and so on.